# In a Chrome Extension, how would I load a URL as popup?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

I want to load a URL as default_popup, not just a static HTML page. I could load a URL with an iframe, but the issue would be that the URL that I am trying to load would not be the same always.

Say I was on stackoverflow.com/random-url, I would perhaps want my Chrome Extension to open up google.com/**stackoverflow.com/random-url**, as an example.

I'm completely new to Chrome Extensions. The best I know is to use iframes but as I said, that won't work unless I could somehow get the current URL of the tab in the static HTML file...

Comment: I don't know what web extensions are capable to do, but did you try `window.open`?

Comment: as above, or the alert(); function?